# How to correctly adjust css layout for Cross Browser?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

Like an authentic numpty I have only been testing in Chrome desktop/mobile and safari mobile. The website is almost perfect layout and functionality wise on those browsers.

I only now remembered that css stuff for Firefox are a bit different, and for IE seems to be vastly different.

My issues:

Firefox.

1. Mobile Nav drop down does not appear (top right corner once main nav collapses into mobile view)

IE 9.

1. Layout is completely broken, most of the positioning for the right rail (start a fundraiser, team list etc), the navigation bar, are all wonky
2. in the Learn more page the drop downs nested in the `<ul>` don't work properly
3. Mobile Nav doesn't appear either
4. for some reason the only page that looks solid in IE9 is the actual registration page, the nav bar and everything look perfect.

For the time being, I am looking for a solution to fix the mobile nav menu that does not appear in Firefox or IE.

This is the webpage : [TestPage](http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR?fr_id=21959&pg=entry)

*Please note that I took over the project roughly half way through so the the navigation and mobile nav was already done by then*

CSS for Mobile Navigation:

```css
    .login-btn,

    .home-btn,

    .reg-pg-btns,

    .aboutevent-btn,

    .learn-btn,

    .donater-btn,

    .provinces-btn,

    .french-btn {

      width: 100%;

      display: block;

    }

    header {

      min-height: 60px;

      margin-bottom: 5%;

    }

    #content {

      margin: 3% auto;

    }

    #more-nav-options {

      width: 100%;

      border-bottom: 5px solid #0079C2;

      background: white;

      float: left;

      border-top: 1px solid grey;

    }

    #more-nav-options a {

      display: block;

      width: 100%;

      padding: 10px 10px 0px 17px;

      height: 40px;

      box-sizing: border-box;

      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

      font: 16px"Rockwell W01", "Rockwell", Georgia, Courier, serif !important;

    }

    nav {

      padding: 0;

      position: relative;

      z-index: 10;

      height: 0;

    }

    nav ul .left,

    .donate-btn,

    nav ul li,

    .donate-btn:hover {

      width: 100%;

      max-width: none;

      margin: 0;

      float: left;

    }

    nav ul li a {

      text-align: center;

      border: none !important;

    }

    .nav {

      width: 100%;

      float: left;

      background: white;

      border-top: 1px solid gray;

    }

    nav ul ul {

      width: 100%;

    }

    .showMenu {

      display: block;

      background: url(http://convio.cancer.ca/mResponsive/images/icons/BT_menu_64.png) no-repeat center;

      background-size: 48px 48px;

      height: 80px;

      right: 0;

      top: 0;

      text-indent: -999999px;

      font-size: 0;

      position: absolute;

      z-index: 11;

      border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD;

    }

    .showMenu2 {

      display: block;

      width: 60px;

      height: 80px;

      right: 0;

      top: 0;

      font-size: 0;

      position: absolute;

      z-index: 11;

      border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD;

    }

    .navbar-nav > li > a {

      padding-top: 10px;

      padding-bottom: 10px;

      line-height: 20px;

    }

    .nav > li > a {

      position: relative;

      display: block;

      padding: 10px 15px;

    }

    nav ul li {

      display: block;

      color: #6B6B6B !important;

      text-decoration: none;

      padding-top: 0px;

      padding-right: 0px;

      padding-left: 0px;

    }

    a {

      color: #FFEE00;

      text-decoration: none;

    }

    a {

      background-color: transparent;

    }

    user agent stylesheet a:-webkit-any-link {

      color: -webkit-link;

      text-decoration: underline;

      cursor: auto;

    }

    Inherited from li.right.hover P,

    LI,

    OL,

    UL,

    TABLE,

    TR,

    TH,

    TD,

    .Explicit {

      font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;

      font-size: 10pt;

    }

    P,

    LI,

    OL,

    UL,

    TABLE,

    TR,

    TH,

    TD,

    .Explicit {

      font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

      font-size: 10pt;

    }

    user agent stylesheet li {

      display: list-item;

      text-align: -webkit-match-parent;

    }

    Inherited from ul.nav.navbar-nav .nav {

      padding-left: 0;

      margin-bottom: 0;

      list-style: none;

    }

    nav ul {

      padding: 0 0px;

      list-style: none;

      position: relative;

      display: inline-table;

      margin: 0;

      width: 100%;

    }

    P,

    LI,

    OL,

    UL,

    TABLE,

    TR,

    TH,

    TD,

    .Explicit {

      font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;

      font-size: 10pt;

    }

    P,

    LI,

    OL,

    UL,

    TABLE,

    TR,

    TH,

    TD,

    .Explicit {

      font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

      font-size: 10pt;

    }

    user agent stylesheet ul,

    menu,

    dir {

      display: block;

      list-style-type: disc;

      -webkit-margin-before: 1em;

      -webkit-margin-after: 1em;

      -webkit-margin-start: 0px;

      -webkit-margin-end: 0px;

      -webkit-padding-start: 40px;

    }

    nav {

      width: 100%;

      max-width: 970px;

      height: 50px;

      margin: 0 auto;

    }

    nav ul ul {

      display: none;

    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {

      display: block;

    }

    nav ul {

      padding: 0 0px;

      list-style: none;

      position: relative;

      display: inline-table;

      margin: 0;

      width: 100%;

    }

    nav ul:after {

      content: "";

      clear: both;

      display: block;

    }

    nav ul li {

      float: left;

    }

    nav ul li:hover a {

      color: #fff;

    }

    nav ul li a {

      display: block;

      color: #6B6B6B !important;

      text-decoration: none;

      padding-top: 0px;

      padding-right: 0px;

      padding-left: 0px;

    }

    nav ul ul {

      border-radius: 0px;

      padding: 0;

      position: absolute;

      top: 100%;

      width: 100%;

      max-width: 190px;

      padding: 15px 0px 0px;

      box-sizing: border-box;

      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

      background: white;

    }

    nav ul ul li {

      float: none;

      position: relative;

    }

    nav ul ul li a {

      padding: 0px 0px 15px 20px;

      color: #6B6B6B;

      font: 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

      text-align: left;

      box-sizing: border-box;

      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    }

    nav ul ul li a:hover {

      color: black !important;

      text-shadow: none;

    }

    nav ul ul ul {

      position: absolute;

      left: 100%;

      top: 0;

    }

    .main-nav-btn {

      width: 100%;

      height: 50px;

      box-sizing: border-box;

      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

      padding: 14px 0px 0px 10px;

      border-top: 5px solid;

      float: left;

      background-color: white;

      margin-right: 15px;

      font: 15px"Rockwell W01", "Rockwell", Georgia, Courier, serif !important;

    }

    .home-btn {

      width: 180px;

      margin-top: 16px;

      color: #FFFFFF !important;

      background-color: #0066CC;

      font: 14px"Rockwell W01", "Rockwell", Georgia, Courier, serif !important;

    }

    .home-btn:hover,

    .home-btnActive {

      color: #FFEE00 !important;

      background: #1975D1;

      font-weight: 900;

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

      .home-btn {

        margin-top: 1px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFF;

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 765px) {

      .home-btn {

        width: 100%;

        margin-top: 1px;

        margin-left: 15px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFF;

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    .tours-btn {

      /* aka Register button */

      width: 200px;

      margin-top: 16px;

      color: #FFFFFF !important;

      background-color: #0066CC;

      font: 14px"Rockwell W01", "Rockwell", Georgia, Courier, serif !important;

    }

    .tours-btn:hover,

    .toursActive {

      color: #FFEE00 !important;

      background: #1975D1;

      font-weight: 900;

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

      .tours-btn {

        width: 100%;

        margin-top: 1px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFF;

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 765px) {

      .tours-btn {

        width: 100%;

        margin-top: 1px;

        margin-left: 15px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFF;

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    .about-btn {

      /* aka Find Fundraiser button */

      display: none;

      width: 195px;

      margin-top: 16px;

      color: #FFFFFF !important;

      background-color: #0066CC;

      font: 14px"Rockwell W01", "Rockwell", Georgia, Courier, serif !important;

    }

    .about-btn:hover,

    .aboutActive {

      color: #FFEE00 !important;

      background: #1975D1;

      font-weight: 900;

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

      .about-btn {

        width: 100%;

        margin-top: 1px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFF;

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 765px) {

      .about-btn {

        width: 100%;

        margin-top: 1px;

        margin-left: 15px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFF;

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    .learn-btn {

      /*learn more button */

      display: none;

      width: 195px;

      margin-top: 16px;

      color: #FFFFFF !important;

      background-color: #0066CC;

      font: 14px"Rockwell W01", "Rockwell", Georgia, Courier, serif !important;

    }

    .learn-btn:hover,

    .learnActive {

      color: #FFEE00 !important;

      background: #1975D1;

      font-weight: 900;

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

      .learn-btn {

        margin-top: 1px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFF;

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 765px) {

      .learn-btn {

        margin-left: 15px;

        margin-top: 1px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        color: #FFF;

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    .donater-btn {

      width: 200px;

      margin-top: 16px;

      box-sizing: border-box;

      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

      color: #FFEE00 !important;

      margin-right: 0px;

      background-color: #0066CC;

      float: right;

      text-transform: uppercase;

      font-weight: 900;

    }

    .donater-btn:hover,

    .donater-btnActive {

      color: #FFEE00 !important;

      background: #1975D1;

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

      .donater-btn {

        width: 100%;

        margin-top: 1px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 604px) {

      .donater-btn {

        width: 100%;

        margin-top: 1px;

        margin-right: -15px;

        border-radius: 12px;

        background-color: #3498db;

        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        display: inline-block;

        text-transform: uppercase;

        letter-spacing: 2px;

        font-size: 12px;

        padding: 10px 30px;

        -moz-border-radius: 12px;

        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

        border-bottom-width: 3px;

        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

    a .donater-btn:hover {

      width: 100%;

      height: 100%;

      display: block;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="responsive-nav" class="showMenu" href="#" title="Navigation Menu">more navigational options</a>

<nav>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li class="left"><a href="http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR?fr_id=[[S80:frID]]&pg=entry" class="home-btn" id="home-btn">Home</a>
      </li>

      <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events/General?pg=informational&fr_id=[[S80:frID]]&type=fr_informational&sid=9700" class="tours-btn" id="tours-btn">Register</a>
      </li>


      <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events?pg=pfind&amp;fr_id=[[S80:frID]]" class="about-btn" id="about-btn">Find a Fundraiser</a>
      </li>


      <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events/General?pg=informational&fr_id=[[S80:frID]]&type=fr_informational&sid=10335" class="learn-btn" id="learn-btn">Learn More</a>
      </li>


      <li class="right"><a href="TR/Events?pg=pfind&amp;fr_id=[[S80:frID]]" class="donater-btn hvr-buzz-out">DONATE</a>
      </li>


      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle provinces-btn" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Province<span class="caret"></span></a> 
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Alberta</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">British Columbia</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Manitoba</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">New Brunswick</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Newfoundland and Labrador</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Nova Scotia</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Nunavut</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Ontario</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Prince Edward Island</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Quebec</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Saskatchewan</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="right"><a href="frenchurl" class="french-btn" title="French">Français</a>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

All suggestions are greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a **specific**, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: My mobile nav disappears in firefox and IE, and I don't know why, right now that's a big issue for me

Comment: So edit the question & code down to that specific issue...make a demo and perhaps you might get on the road to fixing this...one thing at a time.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: oh that's pretty cool didn't know stack had that option. So I tried to replicate the code but it doesn't work the same way it does in the browser, I've even tried copying the entire css into the editor and it still doesn't give the button for drop down. It just appears in mobile form when you change the page size.

Comment: Then try an online code demo site like Codepen.io or JSfiddle.net.

Comment: yeah I did JSfiddle first, but it didn't work in there. I think it's because the webpage is being built around a CMS called Luminate Online there are things that won't work in these simulators...which is weird because I am still using just the affected html and css. I even posted everything in there and it still didn't appear. So I don't know what to do

Comment: Unfortunately then neither do I. If we can't reproduce the issue, we can't debug it.

Comment: fair enough, thanks for your time paulie! I'll keep trying to figure it out maybe i'll create a new drop down menu for firefox